# What is the right place for systemd services created by the system adminstrator on Debian?

Tags: debian, systemd

On my system systemd services are installed under:

- `/usr/lib/systemd/`
- `/etc/systemd/`
- `/lib/systemd/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**According to `man systemd.unit:`**

> UNIT LOAD PATH
>          Unit files are loaded from a set of paths determined during compilation, described in the two tables below. Unit files found in
>   directories listed earlier override files with the same name in
>   directories lower in the list.
>
> ```
>    Table 1.  Load path when running in system mode (--system).
>    +------------------------+-----------------------------+
>    |Path                    | Description                 |
>    +------------------------+-----------------------------+
>    |/etc/systemd/system     | Local configuration         |
>    +------------------------+-----------------------------+
>    |/run/systemd/system     | Runtime units               |
>    +------------------------+-----------------------------+
>    |/usr/lib/systemd/system | Units of installed packages |
>    +------------------------+-----------------------------+
> ```
>
> Additional units might be loaded into systemd ("linked") from directories not on the unit load path. See the link command for
>   systemctl(1). Also, some units are dynamically created via a
>   systemd.generator(7).

Note that `/lib` is just a symlink to `/usr/lib`